# NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10007): Unknown Member

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
    @commands.command(name='rostercheck', aliases=['rc'])
    async def rostercheck(self, ctx, dept_name):
        for dept_name in self.roster.keys():
            print(dept_name)
            google_sheet = await self.get_roster_sheet(dept_name)
            print(google_sheet)
            for value_list in google_sheet.get("values"):
                print(value_list)
                if len(value_list) != 1 or value_list is None or "Discord ID" in value_list:
                    continue
                value = value_list[0] 
                print(value)
                discord_server = await self.bot.fetch_guild(int(self.guild_metadata.get(dept_name)))
                print(discord_server)
                discord_member = await discord_server.fetch_member(int(value))
                print(discord_member)
                if discord_member is None:
                    my_chan = self.bot.get_channel(self.channel_metadata.get(dept_name).get("roster_check"))
                    print(my_chan)
                    await self.send_message(f"{value} - is not in the {dept_name} discord, are you sure they are still in your department?", my_chan)
```

I have ensured it prints everything correctly, so it goes through all the discordid from the google sheets, and then searches them in the discord. But as soon as it reaches someone who isn't in the discord it gets this error: **discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10007): Unknown Member**

Then the code just breaks and the rostercheck command just breaks. I can't find any solutions regarding this on this website or in the documentation.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [in-built discord.py error handling mechanism](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.error) to do something else when the exception occurs.

```py
@rostercheck.error
async def please_dont_break_my_code(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        # Do something here 
        pass
```

However, the better solution in your case is to use a [`try-except` block](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-exception-handling/) which is how it is done in vanilla python.

Comment: A try-except block around `fetch_members` would be probably be the better solution here, as I'm assuming the OP wants to skip any invalid members, not halt the function.

Comment: They both can be used to send the message on fail to fetch the user that the user is invalid so I see no reason for the `try-except` block solution to be better than the `@command.error` solution.

Comment: But in their example, they don't want to stop the for loop, they want to send a message and keep looping. This would be unnecessarily more complicated and difficult using the `command.error` solution. Using the `command.error` solution, the function, and subsequently, the loop, would halt.